# Uniform Integrability is Iterative?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Consider a probability measure $m(\cdot)$ on $Y \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$, so that $m(Y) = 1$.

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a compact set, and $f: X \times Y \rightarrow X$ a locally bounded function, continuous in the first argument, measurable in the second one. Let $|f(x,y)|$ be integrable for all fixed $x \in X$.

Assume that the family of functions $\{ y \mapsto |f(x,y)|: \ x \in X\}$ is Uniformly Integrable.

Say if the following family of functions is Uniformly Integrable as well.
$$ \{ y \mapsto | f( f(x,y),y ) |: \ x \in X \} $$

Notes.

Definition of Uniform Integrability (UI) from [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability).

$\mathcal{F} := \{ y \mapsto |f(x,y)|: \ x \in X\}$ is UI if

$$ \lim_{c \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{ x \in X } \int_{\{y: \ |f(x,y)|\geq c \}} |f(x,y)| m(dy) = 0 $$

Comment.

I think this is interesting because it would show if the composition of functions preserves UI.

Comment: I guess that some additional conditions should be added to $f$. For instance, we may want that for all given $x \in X$ the composition $y \mapsto f(f(x,y),y)$ is integrable as well.